# Powershell Script to unzip password protected archives

Tags: powershell, 7zip

There are many different ways, that promise, that it should be possible to unzip a password protected 7zip file, but neither of these did work by my.

So I ask again is somebody can help me?

I have a text file containing a lot of possibles password values. I Read in the single vales and iterate them. Then I try to execute a command, which cause 7zip to unzip it. But I had no success. Indeed I tried it out for hours.

Can you please help me? This is the script code so far

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zipfilePath = "D:\NEU\CP 77 M2\CP.77_M2.part01.rar"
$content = Get-Content "C:\JDownloader v2.0\cfg\org.jdownloader.extensions.extraction.ExtractionExtension.passwordlist.json"
$destinationUnzipPath = Split-Path $zipfilePath
$passwords = ConvertFrom-Json $content

foreach ($password in $passwords)
{
    sz x  $zipfilePath $destinationUnzipPath -p"{password}";

    if (-Not $?)
    {
        [console]::beep(500,300)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the format of `passwordlist.json`? What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the password list is imported properly, the issue is that different passwords are never used in the foreach loop. Let's take a closer look:

```
# $passwords will now contain iterable set of passwords
$passwords = ConvertFrom-Json $content

# Try each password in the collection
# NB: it is bad practice to use variables with very similar names,
# though it is not the problem here    
foreach ($password in $passwords)
{
    # Call 7zip. Provide password as an argument.
    # Always use string literal {password} as decryption password.
    sz x  $zipfilePath $destinationUnzipPath -p"{password}";
```

So the issue is that even though a `foreach` is used, the individual passwords are never tried. As for a fix, pass the password as a variable. Like so,

```
# $passwords will now contain iterable set of passwords
$passwords = ConvertFrom-Json $content

# Try each password in the collection
foreach ($pass in $passwords)
{
    # Call 7zip. Provide password as an argument.
    sz x  $zipfilePath $destinationUnzipPath -p"$pass"
```